# Parse Push to AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform

I am in the process of migrating my iOS app from Parse to AWS and am stuck on Parse Push -> AWS SNS. The message is published successfully through AWS but never arrives on the device (tried multiple devices). Working with an AWS person unfamiliar with mobile who also thinks it should work. Anyone else experienced this?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: No, the AWS console says the message is sent successfully. The device says subscription is active and matches the ARN in the AWS console.

Comment: Create a topic for failures and subscribe to it. Some details here. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/DeliveryPolicies.html

Answer (score 1):

AWS SNS is weird when it comes to message formats. Are you sending it as a JSON object? 
If yes, then you will have to add that attribute to your message payload. In python it is like - `sns.publish(TargetArn= <your-endpoint>, Message= json.dumps(<your-message-dictionary-object>),MessageStructure = 'json')`

I'm assuming system wide notification settings are turned ON on the iOS device.

Another helpful thing is to subscribe to delivery failures for the application in the SNS dashboard. Goto Applications -> choose your application -> Actions -> Configure events -> Delivery Failures. Here you can specify ARN for a lambda function, a SNS topic(which then sends emails to you) etc. 
An example of a delivery failure email is -

> {"DeliveryAttempts":1,"EndpointArn":"< your mobile endpoint
>   ARN>","EventType":"DeliveryFailure","FailureMessage":"Platform token
>   associated with the endpoint is not
>   valid","FailureType":"InvalidPlatformToken","MessageId":"< some-value>","Resource":"< your
>   application arn>","Service":"SNS","Time":"< some-value>"}